# INSERT INTO (SQL server) command failing in Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, insert

I am trying to read a text file, save the row in a list and then trying to INSERT the row in an SQL Server table. I had tried hardcoding the values in the same code and it worked. But when I am trying to move the values from the list index then it is failing with a syntax error.

### Can you please review the code and let me know where is the mistake.

```
import pyodbc

f= open('temp.txt', 'w')
con1 = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server};"
    "Server=DESKTOP-QP4DVEP;"
    "Database=Customer;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
cursor = con1.cursor()

def write_sql():
    query1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer_Master] ([Cust_ID],[Cust_FName],[Cust_LName],[Cust_PNo], 
    [Cust_Country])" \
    "VALUES(list1[0],list1[1],list1[2],list1[3],list1[4])"

    cursor.execute(query1)

list1=[]
with open('Cust1.txt','r') as file1:
    data1 = file1.readlines()
for row in data1:
    list1 = row.split(',')
    print(list1[1])
    write_sql()
```

Comment: If you look at the contents of your query1 variable you'll see that this is not a valid sql query... concatenate your query and variables....

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Give this a try:

```
import pyodbc

f= open('temp.txt', 'w')
con1 = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server};"
    "Server=DESKTOP-QP4DVEP;"
    "Database=Customer;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
cursor = con1.cursor()

def write_sql(plist):  #Add a parameter here to accept the list
    #Parameterize the query
    query1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer_Master] ([Cust_ID],[Cust_FName],[Cust_LName],[Cust_PNo],[Cust_Country]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"

    #the plist corresponds to the values in the above query
    cursor.execute(query1, (plist[0], plist[1], plist[2], plist[3], plist[4], plist[5]))

    #Commit the transaction
    cursor.commit()

list1=[]
with open('Cust1.txt','r') as file1:
    data1 = file1.readlines()
for row in data1:
    list1 = row.split(',')
    print(list1[1])
    write_sql(list1) #Pass the list to the function
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your help. I tried this code but getting following error.        
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/idcni/PycharmProjects/Nikhil Sample Projects -2020/File Operation3.py", line 39, in <module>
    write_sql(list1)
  File "C:/Users/idcni/PycharmProjects/Nikhil Sample Projects -2020/File Operation3.py", line 30, in write_sql
    cursor.execute(query1,(plist1[0],plist1[1],plist1[2],plist1[3],plist1[4]))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 5 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: @NikhilShingade I updated the code, change the %s to ? in query1

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, It worked very well. Learned a lot.

Comment: @NikhilShingade You're welcome, glad I could help.  If this answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in.